# How to interact with sites in wp7?

Tags: silverlight, http, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I need to send and receive get post requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `HttpWebRequest` / `HttpWebResponse` classes or simpler requirements can be fulfilled with `WebClient`.  The [HTTP Communication and Security with Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) topic on MSDN covers the basics.

Note that Windows Phone 7 is basically Silverlight 3 not 4 especially when it comes to networking capabilities.  The [Networking in Silverlight for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637320%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) topic is also worth reading.